# pyexcel : Save in downloads folder the xls file exported

Tags: python, pyexcel

I'm new with pyexcel, i'm programing in django and python and i export an array with the folowing code

```
pyexcel.isave_as(array=array_of_data, dest_file_name=('%(name)s.xls') % {'name':model.name})
```

my problem is the file is exported and save it but, i dont want to save it in the program folder, i want to select that the .xls is downloaded in the downloads folder

Comment: usually something like `dest_file_name` will save it to the current directory unless you specific a full path. So, try putting the full path there, like `r'C:\users\my_user\downloads\' + '%(name)s.xls'`, something like that

Comment: this is a web application, so, i don't know the user's name directory

Comment: you may be able to use the pathlib library for that. `pathlib.Path.home()` will return the home directory. You can then build on this with `joinpath()`. So fully, you would have `pathlib.Path.home().joinpath('downloads',f'{model.name}.xls')`. I also changed the filename string to an f-string because I don't know that string-formating system very well.